# removing space before new line in java

Tags: java, newline

i have a space before a new line in a string and cant remove it (in java).
I have tried the following but nothing works:

```
strToFix = strToFix.trim();
strToFix = strToFix.replace(" \n", "");
strToFix = strToFix.replaceAll("\\s\\n", "");
```

Comment: Since `trim()` didn't work... are you sure you have " \n"? There are some oddball characters out there that show up as normal whitespace despite not being the standard space or newline characters.

Comment: show your code with trim() and print the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString.replaceAll("[ \t]+(\r\n?|\n)", "$1");
```

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression as an argument.  The `[ \t]` matches one or more spaces or tabs.  The `(\r\n?|\n)` matches a newline and puts the result in `$1`.

Comment: You understand it. Yet to remove the `)` in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with this one you should try this instead:

```
strToFix = strToFix.replace(" \\n", "\n");
```

Edit:

I forgot the escape in my original answer. James.Xu in his answer reminded me.

Comment: There can be more than one space before the newline. This one only removes the last one.

Comment: Very true. However, the op said "i have a space", which implies one space. If there was more than one space, this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> strToFix = strToFix.replaceAll(" \\n", "\n");

'\' is a special character in regex, you need to escape it use '\'.

Comment: Oops, i forgot the escape in my answer. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?

```
String s1 = "hi     ";
System.out.println("|" + s1.trim() + "|");

String s2 = "hi     \n";
System.out.println("|" + s2.trim() + "|");
```

prints

```
|hi|
|hi|
```

Comment: The OP wants to only remove the spaces before newline, not the newline itself.

Comment: @Balus, not so, the second example clearly removes the newline character as well.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think showing the OP how `trim()` is supposed to work is much use when he's already stated that it's not working in his case.

Comment: @Lord: that's exactly what should *not* happen :) Only the spaces (char 32) should be removed, not the newline (char 13).

Comment: @Balus, I guess it depends on the OP's intent; I'm assuming that his removal of the newline was intentional rather than a separate bug.

Comment: @Lord: that would contradict with the OP's question title and body.

Comment: @Lord, The OP appears to believe the method doesn't work when it does. The problem is more likely that a) he hasn't a clear idea what he means by "doesn't work" b) the text isn't what he thinks it is. c) he hasn't looked at this in a debugger. ;)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it is a space what you're trying to remove? You should print string bytes and see if the first byte's value is actually a 32 (decimal) or 20 (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

trim() seems to do what your asking on my system.  Here's the code I used, maybe you want to try it on your system:

```
public class so5488527 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String testString1 = "abc \n";
        String testString2 = "def \n";
        String testString3 = "ghi \n";
        String testString4 = "jkl \n";
        testString3 = testString3.trim();
        System.out.println(testString1);
        System.out.println(testString2.trim());
        System.out.println(testString3);
        System.out.println(testString4.trim());
    }
}
```