# removing one or more white spaces before a newline from the text file

Tags: java, regex, newline

I have a text file which contains email headers and its value. looks like below:

```
X-Originating-IP: [141.12.67.171]
X-EIP: [WrrdRE5IHzynFRch2UnizIKJ909XPTq5]
X-Originating-Email: [reva.reva.reva@hotmail.com]
Message-ID: <SNT139-W588104AB227AA9D1E443ABCF540@phx.gbl>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="_ee82adcf-0995-439f-a6dc-4386dadf9660_"
From: Reva Patil <reva.reva.reva@hotmail.com>  
To: <mueller.reva@yahoo.de>
Subject: Hotmail
Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2012 12:34:46 +0000
Importance: Normal
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 21 Nov 2012 12:34:47.0075 (UTC) FILETIME=[976F7F30:01CDC7E4]
```

I have noticed that in the line which starts from "From:" (with winmerge file comparing tool), there are white spaces before a newline. I would like to remove it. Actually I would like to remove all white spaces before each newline in a file. I have already gone through the  posted question here : [removing space before new line in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488527/removing-space-before-new-line-in-java)
But that did not help me unfortunately.

I would appreciate any advices to do this in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses.

Finally I could found regular expression which removes all white spaces (including non breaking white space) from a string.

```
str= str.replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Guava`

read file:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/test.txt").getFile());
List<String> lines = null;
try {
    lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`trim()` each line.

write those lines again

using: [Files#write](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#write%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

EDIT:

```
    File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/test.txt").getFile());
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> trimmedLines = new ArrayList<String>(lines.size());

    File to; /// outputfile
    Charset charSet = Charset.defaultCharset();
    for (String line : lines) {
        Files.write(line.trim(), to, charSet);
    }
```

Comment: I tried trim but that does not seem to work..I tried exactly what u said.

Comment: @user523956 see my edit. Maybe you did sth like: `line.trim();         Files.write(line, file, charSet);`

Comment: I am really sorry for late trying..but it seems that my eclipse can not find charsets so it gives error in line below (lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8); ) any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: @user523956  `Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); ` try this. `cahrsets` class are part of `Guava` and maybe you ignored my sugestion to use that library... so try with `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the file as a String, do this

```
String trimmed = contents.replaceAll("(?m)\\s+(?=$)", "");
```

Explanation:

- `(?m)` turns on the "caret and dollar match after and before newlines" switch
- `\s+` means "one or more whitespace characters
- `(?=$)` means the next character (not consumed) is an end-of-line character

Comment: I tried this by extracting each line of a file to a string. That did not work.

Comment: @user523956 I just realised - the `\n` and `\r` didn't need *two* backslashes - try the edited version

Comment: @user523956 try in now - it was missing a closing bracket on the look-ahead (you should have got an error trying it), but I just realised there's a better way to do it - see edited answer. btw I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: well this works for some strings and does not seem to work for some...I dont know why. may be some problem with the input string but not able to figure out why it does not work for some..I checked the input file in notepad++ but could not see any strange thing which might make it not to work. :-(

Comment: I just found out why it was not working for particular string. That string contained non breaking white space and your regular expression was not able to remove it.

Comment: "non breaking" whitespace??? There's no such thing AFAIK. Do you mean `&nbsp;` - the HTML non-breaking space?